# AskUbuntu API returns wrong colours

Tags: bug, status-completed

Calling the [stats method](http://api.askubuntu.com/1.0/stats?type=jsontext) of the AskUbuntu API returns [the wrong colours](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5700/can-i-install-ubuntu-software-center-and-indicator-sound-from-10-10-on-10-04).

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Yup, that's not quite the right colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New styling values have been pushed to the API.  They'll start showing up everywhere as things fall out of cache (StackAuth is already reporting them).

Naturally, as the recent graduates are still experiencing minor styling tweaks these values may still be a little out of sync until everything settles down.